# MIPS difference between 0($s1) and $s1

Tags: mips, mips32

I am new in mips. In my practice I am sometimes confused with the differences between `number($s1)` and `$s1`.

e.g.

```
la $a0, $s1       # wrong
la $a0, 0($s1)    # right
```

Is there any explaination? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `la $a0, $s1` makes no sense. `la` stands for Load Address, and you would use it in situtations like `la $a0, my_var  # a0 = address of my_var`. A register doesn't have an address. If you just wanted to copy the value in `$s1` to `$a0` you would use `move $a0, $s1`

Comment: @Michael What's the meaning of `la $a0, 0($s1)`?  Which address does `0($s1)` represent?

Comment: `la $a0, 0($s1)` probably has the same meaning as `move $a0, $s1`. You can check this in a simulator like SPIM/MARS.